# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT - Xcode crashes after executing

Tags: c, xcode

I get an error when building (after getting the required result).

> 0x7fff6acd623e <+10>: jae    0x7fff6acd6248            ; <+20>

What can be the issue?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[100], i, j = 2, jump, k, sum =0 ;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)                       //input numbers from 2 -> to limit of arrSize
        arr[i] = j++;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)                       //if the value of arr[i] isnt already = 0, then jump
    {                                               //will get the value of i (e.g. 3), and jump 3 steps,
        if (arr[i] != 0)                            //not including 0 values.
        {

            jump = arr[i];
            for (k = jump; k < 100; k+=jump)        //then it will assign value 0.
                arr[i+k] = 0;
        }

        else
            continue;                               //if arr[i] = 0, it will go to the next iteration
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)                       //print all numbers. the not-prime will be 0.
        printf("%d\n ", arr[i]);                    //it can be improved by copying not 0 values to other arr
                                                    //but for summing up it don't make any different.
}
```

Comment: As i said, i get the expected resault although the error. But whe trying values small or equal to 20 (and changing it in the for loops) i dont get an error.

Comment: How did you try to debug your problem?

Comment: Im sorry. Im not completely ubderstand. I ran the program if works fine. The error is after extexuting and exiting the program . I didnt run debug while the program runs because it fails at the end of execution.

Comment: This is confusing. Is Xcode crashing or is your app crashing? Your title states a crash after executing but your question refers to an error when building. Which is it? A build error or a runtime error? Please [edit] your question and clarify these issues.

Comment: the `else continue` is not needed as already at the end of the `for()` loop

Comment: OT: the posted code contains several instances of the 'magic' number 100.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `#define` statement or a `enum` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name, then using that meaningful name throughout the code

Comment: regarding: `arr[i+k] = 0;` this statement will set memory beyond the end of the array `arr[]`   The result will be 'stack smashing' and the program aborting